# add nav controller to tabbed application

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.2

Good day. I try to add new tab with navigation controller to my app. I create a new tabbed app (xcode 4.2) and in appdelegate write this

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UIViewController *viewController1 = [[[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    UIViewController *viewController2 = [[[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    NavController *navController = [[[NavController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NavController" bundle:nil] autorelease]; //my controller
    self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2, navController, nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

NavController.h file

```
@interface NavController : UINavigationController

@end
```

Here the structure of project
[image: Structure of progect]

And when I run project it show me empty tab
[image: result]
But in xib file I add lable and buttons
[image: What I want in result]
May be I forgot something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialise your navigation controller with some UIViewController that is :

```
    RootViewController *rootViewController = [[[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    NavController *navController = [[[NavController alloc] initWithRootViewController: rootViewController] autorelease];
```

This might help.

Answer (score 0):

i am sharing you my APP Code about this feature,Hope this can solve your Problem easily

Add this code in AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];

    UINavigationController *localNavigationController;

    tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

    NSMutableArray *localControllersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3];

    viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    localNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
    [localControllersArray addObject:localNavigationController];

    AlaramClock *aAlaramClock = [[[AlaramClock alloc] initWithNibName:@"AlaramClock" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    localNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:aAlaramClock];
    [localControllersArray addObject:localNavigationController];


    CurrentTime *aCurrentTime = [[[CurrentTime alloc] initWithNibName:@"CurrentTime" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    localNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:aCurrentTime];
    [localControllersArray addObject:localNavigationController];

    Settings *aSettings = [[[Settings alloc] initWithNibName:@"Settings" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    localNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:aSettings];
    [localControllersArray addObject:localNavigationController];



    tabBarController.viewControllers = localControllersArray;

    [localControllersArray release];


    // Override point for customization after app launch    
    [window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Then U will get this look

[image]

after this in Every ViewController.m

ADD this

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil 
{
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) 
    {
        // Custom initialization
        self.title=@"Calculate Time";
        self.tabBarItem.title = @"Calculate Time";
        self.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"time_calculate.png"];
    }

    return self;

}
```

Comment: tried to add this in delegate                       UINavigationController *localNavigationController;
    NavController *navController = [[[NavController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NavController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    localNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:navController];  But it crashed in initWithRootControllerMethod